# Bayes rule application?

Tags: probability

In a bag there are six balls of unknown colors; three balls are drawn at random and found to be all black. Find the probability that no black ball is left in the bag. In other words, you have to find the probability that the bag contained exactly three black balls.

Attempted solution:

A= 3 draws are all black.
B= number of black balls in the bag originally.

Apply Bayes rule:

P(B=3|A)= P(A|B=3)P(B=3)/P(A).

My issue is I can’t compute P(B=k).

Is their more information being assumed to make that computation?
Or an alternative way to solve the problem?

Remark: I did google up this question. I am unconvinced by the argument. The answer posted takes the  form of Bayes but missing the P(B=k) factors.

Can be found at:

https://www.toppr.com/ask/en-us/question/in-a-bag-there-are-six-balls-of-unknown-colors/

Comment: How many colours are there?

Comment: There is not enough information to do the computation. The answer given in the link is assuming that the cases with 3,4,5 or 6 balls are equally likely, which is nowhere stated in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can easy solve the problem counting the combinations. The number of total colours is not needed

$$\frac{\binom{3}{3}}{\binom{3}{3}+\binom{4}{3}+\binom{5}{3}+\binom{6}{3}}=\frac{1}{35}$$

Comment: What if I put six golf balls in a bag and you pull three white balls out of the bag? What is the probability that there are no more white balls in the bag?